# Factorial of a large number

Tags: c, biginteger

I am doing a program where I have to find factorial of a large number, like of 100 whose answer is of 158 digits and I was suggested to use BigInteger in C.
What is BigInteger and how can i use it.

Comment: @JackV It is not answered even their. If you know the solution then please tell me.

Comment: That question provides several pointers to big-integer libraries, etc.  In what sense is that insufficient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17039284/971127

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28035571/971127

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger is a class in the standard Java libraries.  For C, you want to use [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: can you tell me how can i use GMP

Comment: I haven't used it much myself, however there is plenty of documentation at the provided link, particularly the chapter on [integer functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Functions.html).