# try to make a factorial program in C

Tags: c, factorial

Fortunately this program works fine to find the factorials of 1 to 12 but after 12 as 13, 14, 20 ..... output getting wrong and i also try to find the factorial of 40 and the output was 0.
Failed to find the exact problem...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   int user_input, tbl;

   printf("Enter any number: \t");
   scanf("%i", &user_input);

   tbl = user_input; 

   for(int i=2; i < user_input; i++) {
      tbl = tbl * i;
   }

    printf("Factorial of %i is %i", user_input, tbl);

}
```

Comment: Did you check the max value an `int` can hold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C / Find 190! (factorial) in c programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744538/c-find-190-factorial-in-c-programming)

Comment: @forweb check out [Ridiculously Large Number Multiplication](https://gist.github.com/jargnar/3263916), it provider a way to multiply numbers as string, which gives you ability to multiply numbers with almost no limit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032886/calculate-the-sum-of-digits-in-100-factorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). On most machines, `int` is 32 bit wide (and obviously signed). That means the biggest number it can represent is 2^31-1 which is 2147483648. 12! works as it's 479001600 (which is smaller than 2^31-1) but 13! is 6227020800. So 13! can't usually be represented in an `int`.

One option you have is to make `i`, `user_input` and `tbl` a bigger type for example a `unsigned long long` or a `uint64_t` (from `#include <inttypes.h>`). But these types will also have a maximum representable number.

If you actually need arbitrary precision in C, you might want to consider [GMP (The GNU
Multiple Precision
Arithmetic Library)](https://gmplib.org/).

Also please be aware that overflows of signed types have undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: thanks and is it possible to check integer length with in a program ?

Comment: @forweb it's a compile time property. You can query the length of an a type in bytes using `sizeof`. For example `sizeof(int)` will most likely be `4` for you. `CHAR_BITS` tells you how many bits a byte has (almost always `8`).

Comment: @forweb if you're interested in the maximum number an `int` can hold, `#include <limits.h>` does have `INT_MAX` (which is probably 2147483647 == 2^32-1).

Comment: @JohannesWeiß 2^31-1

Comment: @JohannesWeiß thanks, and can we use 'double' to increase the size ?

Comment: No need to check `sizeof int`.  Every C implementation has a `<limits.h>` that contains a set of macros which expand to maximum values for all numeric types, among others.   For example, `INT_MAX` is the maximum value of the (implementation defined) `int` type.   For the more recent fixed-width integral types there is also a set of macros in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @forweb not really, double are floating number, so you won't get an integer

Comment: @Guiroux then how we can increase the size of a integer?

Comment: @forweb well the answer actually told you, use **unsigned long long**

Answer (score 0):

- 8bit unsigned char Max:0xFF-->255 ->2^8 - 1 (char)2^7 -1
- 16bit unsigned short Max:0xFFFF -->2^16 - 1(short)2^15 - 1
- 32bit unsigned int Max:0xFFFFFFFF -->2^32 - 1(int)2^31 - 1
- 64bit unsigned.....Max:...  -->     2^64 - 1(long long)2^63 - 1
- All have Range.This is not the number written on the paper.